# Arquivos dando erro 404

Tags: html, angularjs, route

Minha aplicação é simples, eu fiz com AngularJS, só para estudar, funciona tranquilamente localmente mas quando eu subo para o meu servidor da locaweb, os arquivos ficam retornando 404, tem alguma configuração que eu precise fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E minha aplicação eu deixei bem configurada.**

**Index.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title>Busca CEP</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1' />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=0,minimum-scale=1" />
  <link href='/favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' />
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.9/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/style.min.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

  <div ui-view=""></div>
  <toaster-container></toaster-container>

  <script src="/dist/vendors.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/app/app.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**route.js:**

```js
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',

  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider

      .state({
        name: 'home',
        url: '/',
        controller: 'homeController',
        templateUrl: '/views/home.html'
      });
  }
]);
```

**Minha estrutura está basicamente assim:**

- app
- assets
- dist
- vendors
- views
- index.html

Comment: SIm, mas não pega a pasta, ele não consegue achar o endereço correto

Comment: Guilherme acredito que estaja faltando um ponto " . " no caminho dos seus arquivos. tente colocar o link do href começando com um **.** e veja se funciona, dessa forma: **"./dist/style.min.css"** *(e confere se o "style.min.css" está na raiz da pasta "dist" !)*